# Embedded ActiveMQ with local producers and remote consumers

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ embedded in my java code (instead of starting a standalone ActiveMQ process).  The producers and broker are on the same server (`192.168.1.1`) which remote consumers (on server `192.168.1.2`) should fetch messages from.

Is it possible for my producers to connect to ActiveMQ via `vm://localhost:PORT` and the remote consumers to connect via `tcp://192.168.1.1:PORT`?

Is there any performance gain by using suggested mechanism in compare with current scenario which both producer and consumer are using `tcp://192.168.1.1:PORT` as broker endpoint?

Comment: It is possible , producers  can use `vm://localhost:PORT` & consumers can use `tcp://192.168.1.1:PORT`. There should be some performance gain , since no network check / trips when using `vm://localhost.....`

Comment: what should i use in `TransportConnector.setUri` when starting the borker: `vm://localhost:PORT` or  `tcp://192.168.1.1:PORT`?

Comment: I mean how to tell the broker that producers would be connected via vm and consumers via tcp?

Comment: In the Java Code (Producer code) should use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");  Connection connection = factory.createConnection();` to get JMS connection. The same way Consumer code should use `tcp://192.168.1.1:PORT`